# need help saving image files

Tags: java, android, save

I am trying to save signature pad image to file but my app doesn't seem to be creating the directory in `storage/emulated/0`

this is what I am using to create the folder...

```
    String DIRECTORY = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Signature/";
    String pic_name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String StoredPath = DIRECTORY + pic_name + ".png";
```

and this is what I am using to create the directory

```
        file = new File(DIRECTORY);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
```

and finally,  this is where the file is saved...

```
        public void save(View v, String StoredPath) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
            Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
            if (bitmap == null) {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvasLL.getWidth(), canvasLL.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            }
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            try {
                // Output the file
                FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(StoredPath);
                v.draw(canvas);

                // Convert the output file to Image such as .png
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
                mFileOutStream.flush();
                mFileOutStream.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
            }

        }
```

Please note that this is not my own code...
(Basically a copy and paste from) 
http://demonuts.com/android-capture-signature-using-canvas/

The pad works fine, I can write on it, but it won't save :(
When I send it to a Toast I can return the full directory and file name of `Storage/emulated/0/Signature/20191101_a time stamp.png` but it wont save on device.

Any ideas??

Comment: add the storage permission in the manifest file and try again

Comment: `if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }`. That should be: `if (!file.exists()) if (! file.mkdir()){ Toast (could..not..make..directory); return;}`.
        }`

Comment: On Android Q you have no access to that external storage location.

Comment: `and finally, this is where the file is saved...` If you cannot create a directory then you dont need to post code for creating a file in that directory.

Comment: `The pad works fine, I can write on it, ` What do you mean? Which path exactly? PLease show your code.

Comment: thank you for your responses Blackapps but I am still having problems creating a path to save images to.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file, To grant external storage read write permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

For Android OS version > 6.0, you require **run time  permissions** as well.

```
// Check whether this app has write external storage permission or not.
int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ExternalStorageActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

// If do not grant write external storage permission.
if(permission!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
    // Request user to grant write external storage permission.
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ExternalStorageActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mayuri.  I have my permissions in the Manifest but it seems I am still doing something wrong (forgive my lack of knowledge, I only picked up android studio 2 months ago)

Comment: I am able to take a picture and display it in an ImageView, but I haven't quite figured out how to save it in my pictures directory.  What I am hoping to do is create a subdirectory if it doesn't already exist, and save the ImageView image to it.  Would you be aware of some good tutorials on-line?

Comment: Can you check if you are able to create and save file on an external dir ?. That way you can identify if you have a (1) externl storage problem (2) image wrongly capture problem

Comment: Hi.  I have experimented with other camera app tutorials and have been able to save to pictures folder so i am pretty sure it is in my capture coding.  I think what i might do is try to perform all of the save image methods from a separate button click. The activity is an entry form for a database so i could add the button click events to the save function of the database...   saving the image to file, and the path to the image to the database.

Comment: As shown in the original question, this was about a signature pad I was creating, yet my comments have turned to a camera image displayed in an imageview.  I have set the signature pad aside for a while and am focusing in the camera image...  but I believe they are both a part of the same issue.
The imageview will display a picture obtained from the camera, and the signatureview will accept my finger writing....   but I cant seem to figure out how to save the images each one produces.  
Sorry if I created any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help...   my problem was creating a drive to save to.  I found my answer at https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-a-folder-in-internal-and-external-storage-programmatically-in-an-Android-app

I should be able to create and save the file now    thanks